# How do I add a statement in a variable when part of the statement is variable and the variables value is too be assigned?

Tags: python-3.x, string, variables

So I have two variables `s` and `c`. Both are strings with one word.
I have a third variable `a`.

Let's say -

```
s=Nevad
c=Carson City
```

The code I ran was -

```
a=(s," is the capital of ",c)
```

So when I print `a` the output I get is -

```
('Nevad', ' is the capital of ', 'Carson City')
```

The output I want is

```
Nevad is the capital of Carson City
```

Also, can I possibly store 5 sentences in `a`, treating it like list?If so when I print `a` with multiple sentences I would like the output to be -

```
Nevad is the capital of Carson City
Massachusett is the capital of Boston
```

And so on until all the sentences are printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a string formatter:

```
In [1]: s = "Nevada"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [2]: c = "Carson City"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [3]: a = "{} is the capital of {}".format(c, s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [4]: a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[4]: 'Carson City is the capital of Nevada'
```